# How include the Swiper slider html in Magento2.2.6?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I tried i include the swiper.min js. but not working.

https://idangero.us/swiper/demos/080-scrollbar.html

i added this slider in our product phtml file then coming error please let me know how we can fix this screenshot.
http://prntscr.com/lmbmis

http://magento-213836-648260.cloudwaysapps.com/demo
this is my site link.

Comment: please add the code you've tried.

Comment: http://magento-213836-648260.cloudwaysapps.com/demo

Comment: Frontend link doesn't help.

Comment: please check console error. http://prntscr.com/lmbzuc,  http://prntscr.com/lmbzzj

Comment: Kindly add the code to the question as well, preferably not as a screenshot.

Comment: i implement "https://idangero.us/swiper/demos/080-scrollbar.html" html in over product file if it work fine then i convert in dynamic.

Comment: (function  () {
        require(["jquery","swipeslider"],function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                                   scrollbar: {
         el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
         hide: true,
          },
                                  slidesPerView: 4,
          spaceBetween: 30,
          slidesPerGroup: 1,
          loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
        });       
            });
        });
    })();

Comment: <script src="http://magento-213836-648260.cloudwaysapps.com/app/design/frontend/Cloudways/m2-theme/web/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

Comment: Did you checked my ans ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't work properly with third part js libraries, if not included using require js.
You've just added script in the body.
Check this post to include js library with jquery dependency;

[How to add js libraries that require Jquery to magento 2 using requireJs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163858/how-to-add-js-libraries-that-require-jquery-to-magento-2-using-requirejs)

Comment: https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/080-scrollbar.html

Comment: i used this jquery slider

Comment: Copy the code from your phtml and paste it in the question.

Comment: Our theme require.config.js code "var config = {
    paths: {            
            'js': "Magento_Theme/js/swiper.min"
        },   
    shim: {
        'js': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};"

Comment: <script src="http://magento-213836-648260.cloudwaysapps.com/app/design/frontend/Cloudways/m2-theme/web/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script>
require(['jquery', 'glide', 'domReady!'], function($, glide){
    $(function(){
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                                   scrollbar: {
         el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
         hide: true,
          },
                                  slidesPerView: 4,
          spaceBetween: 30,
          slidesPerGroup: 1,
          loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
        }); 
    });
});

 
</script>